# My loop displays only the last value in JSON, How to display all in JSON file

Tags: c#, json, serialization

[I want to Display All of data of forloop
in JSON file because the output is only the last digits of the forloop
Anyone can Help me to the proper logic?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkayf.png)

```
            Console.Write("Enter your range: ");
            int range = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int cand = 1;
          

            var multiplication = new Multiplication();
            while (cand < range + 1)         
            {
                for (int plier = 1; plier < 11; plier++)
                {
                    int result = cand * plier;
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("Multiplicand : " + cand);
                    Console.WriteLine("Multiplier : " + plier);
                    Console.WriteLine("Product : " + result + "\n");

                    var multiplications = new List<Multiplication>
                    {

                        new Multiplication
                        {
                            multiplicand = cand,
                            multiplier = plier,
                            product = result
                        },
                   
                        };
                    string strResultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(multiplications);
                    File.WriteAllText(@"multiplication.json", strResultJson);
                }
                cand++;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Apparently you are writing the file on each loop-step with the current value. Collect the values end write it at the and outside the loop

Comment: ["_Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?_"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sorry this is my first time to ask question in this site, I read the proper way of asking a question next time

Comment: What do you want to appear in the JSON?  A jagged 2d list corresponding to `List<List<Multiplication>>`?  Or a flattened list containing all the `List<Multiplication> multiplications` collections rolled into a single array?